# Why use the fragment modifier here?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I've seen the use of `fragment` quite frequently within a Lexing rule, but not quite sure what its use is, or why it cannot just be removed. For example in the following rule:

```
NUMBER
    : DECIMAL ([Ee] [+-]?[0-9]+)?
    ;

fragment DECIMAL
    : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)? | '.' [0-9]+
    ;
```

When I remove the `fragment` I still get the same parse tree. So what exactly is the use of using fragment or is it mainly an annotative type of thing?

As another example from this [tutorial page](https://riptutorial.com/antlr/example/11233/fragments):

> Fragments are reusable parts of lexer rules which cannot match on their own - they need to be referenced from a lexer rule.
>
> ```
> INTEGER: DIGIT+
>        | '0' [Xx] HEX_DIGIT+
>        ;
> fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
> fragment HEX_DIGIT: [0-9A-Fa-f];
> ```

I see no difference from using the following two approaches:

[image]

And without `fragment`s:

[image]

Could someone please explain why these would be useful then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fragment` declaration prevents the part from being recognized as a token. That might not be *necessary* very often, but it can definitely save you from hard-to-find bugs.

Let's take the second example in your post, without the `fragment` modifiers:

```
expression: INTEGER ;

INTEGER: DIGIT+
       | '0' [Xx] HEX_DIGIT+
       ;
DIGIT: [0-9];
HEX_DIGIT: [0-9A-Fa-f];
```

Now, we decide that we want to add variables to the grammar:

```
expression: INTEGER  | IDENTIFIER ;

INTEGER: DIGIT+
       | '0' [Xx] HEX_DIGIT+
       ;
DIGIT: [0-9];
HEX_DIGIT: [0-9A-Fa-f];

IDENTIFIER: LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)+ ;
LETTER: [A-Za-z] ;
```

Do you see the bug?

The parser won't handle the input `a`, although it has no trouble with `ax` or `i`. That's because the tokeniser will interpret  `a` as a `HEX_DIGIT`, not an `IDENTIFIER`.

Of course, I could have prevented that by putting `HEX_DIGIT` after `IDENTIFIER`, but that's more thinking about lexer rule ordering than I really want to do. I'd like the implementation details of `IDENTIFIER` and `INTEGER` to not interfere with each other, thank you very much.

Correctly flagging non-token fragments, like `LETTER`, `DIGIT` and `HEX_DIGIT` saves me from having to think about whether a fragment might somehow manage to high-jack a token definition somewhere else in the file.

Here's a possibly more pernicious example, based on your first example:

```
NUMBER  : DECIMAL EXPONENT? ;
EXPONENT: [Ee] [+-]? [0-9]+ ;
DECIMAL : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)? | '.' [0-9]+ ;
```

Once I add expressions to that grammar, I'll find that `f+17` is fine, but `e+17` is a syntax error. Why? Because it is recognised as an `EXPONENT`, rather than being parsed as an expression. No reordering of lexical rules will prevent that. But adding the `fragment` modifiers does the trick.